# How to check if my app is running in full screen mode?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, fullscreen

I need to check if my app is running in full screen mode. Because I have button witch slides out panel, and it should be sliced differently when in full screen. How can I check it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The window displayed full screen should have `NSFullScreenWindowMask` set.

See [Apple's docs here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Conceptual/MOSXAppProgrammingGuide/FullScreenApp/FullScreenApp.html)

For example you could use:

```
if ([yourwindow styleMask] & NSFullScreenWindowMask) {
  ....it's full screen
}
```

Comment: And how then could I check if this mask is set? Now I do it like that:

    `NSUInteger _full_screen_int = 1 << 14;   
    if ([_main_app_window styleMask] == _full_screen_int) {   
        NSLog(@"full");  
    }`

And it doesn't works

Comment: I'll update the answer, but it's a bit mask (other bits could be set too) so your equals won't work...